# Ember.js: Access the object bound to the form after submitting the form

Tags: ember.js

I have a signup form

In the route I create the new record (with will contain the signup data)

```
App.SignupRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model:function () {
    return App.Fence.createRecord({date:new Date()});}});
```

In the form I checked successfully that the record (fence) is bound to the form elements

Now I would like to have a save button and access the data in the controller method

I tried:

```
< a href="#" {{ action "addsignup" this}}>SignUp</a>
```

and

```
< button type="button" {{action "addsignup" this}}>SignUp</button>
```

The controller method is being called, but I cannot access the fence instance :-(

```
App.SignupController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  addsignup:function (fence) {

    console.log(fence.name);         // => undefined
    console.log(this.name);          // => undefined
    console.log(fence.get("name"));  // => undefined
    console.log(this.get("name"));   // => undefined
```

How can I access the model data in the controller method?

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: What is "this" if you print it directly in the template?

Comment: your action will pass the context.this pointer i believe, i would try passing "content" or nothing in your action tag and look at the debugger and see what i get.

Comment: OMG ... thanks @machunter ... your answer lead to the real cause of the problem: a typo :-( BTW it really doesn't matter whether you use this or the parameter (fence), it's the same object. Same with this.content and fence.content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default, an action passes the view. With

```
{{action "addsignup"}}
```

you can then access the controller and thus its members with

```
addsignup:function () {
    var controller = this.controller;
    var name = controller.name;
}
```

By passing an object in action, you can access it when definition corresponding parameters in the function definition.

hope this helps, ph